# How to connect to a database in a different server using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have moved my database to a different server and my applications files are still in the current server.

I have tried many ways to connect my database in the new server, But still it says

> "Message: mysqli::real_connect() [mysqli.real-connect]: (HY000/2005):
>   Unknown MySQL server host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306' (0)";

this is how my `database.php` is configured

```
'hostname' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306',
'username' => '[my database user]',
'password' => '[my database password]',
'database' => '[my db]',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
```

I appriciate if anyone can provide me a solution

Comment: try the hostname without :3306, port is a separate option and it should probably default to 3306. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: Hi, I have tried without port also. but still same results

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database from the web server at all? Ie using the normal mysql client.

Comment: have you access to `WHM`?

Answer (score 3):

Commonly like this...

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX'; //IP of server 
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database_name';
```

**Note:**

Please allow your **IP** to be access for that database. Maybe that reasons why you can't connect with your remote database,

**Hint:**

- In your **CPanel**, go to **Remote Database Access Hosts** and then set the host as **%** .. its means all IPs can be access to that database.

Comment: I have allowed the IP too. but still I couldn't connect to the database

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you are remotely access *database*, so go to your new server's **Remote MySQL** option, and add write " **%** " ( without quotes ) in **Add an Access Host** textbox, [ to allow Host wildcard entry ] and click to **Add Host** button and then normally access your database configs ( *no need to change your codes* )